# Учебное задание на нахождение погрешности

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток. Нужна помощь. Дана задача:

> Составить программу на языке С++ для вычисления значения и погрешности функции при заданных значениях аргументов дифференциальным способом. Реализовать программное округление результата с точностью до верных цифр.

```
Z= (a+b)/(b^2-3c)    
a=3,45 b=5.781 c=4.1
```

**Добавлено.**

Программа почти написана, нужна толька сама строка погрешности...

```
// функция
double function(double a, double b, double c) {                                 
    return (a+b)/(pow(b,2)-3c);
}

// погрешность 
double dFunction(double a, double b, double c, double da, double db, double dc) {
    return *********** // - ЭТА СТРОКА, вместо звёзд.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Чесслово - не знаю. Предполагаю, что можно пойти от простых соотношений
d(a+b)=da+db
d(a*b)/a*b=d(a)/a+d(b)/b
и т.д. (подсмотрено в учебнике физики за нный класс)

С другой стороны, будучи довольно здравыми и логичными эти формулы совершенно не отражают тот факт, что погрешность есть величина вероятностная. И тогда рассчеты усложняются.

Учитывая, что в предлагаемом Вам методе используется слово "дифференциальный", возможно тут надо как-то высчитывать производную от ф-ции.

В любом случае, как только получите формулу для погрешности, вписать ее в программу будет не самой большой проблемой. Так что задача не на программирование как таковое, а скорее на усвоение учебного материала.

Comment: Насколько я припоминаю курс математики, производная -- это тангенс угла между графиком функции и абсциссой. Отсюда, можно применить дифференциальный метод, но только для линейной функции, где производная постоянна.